# Woocommerce, recognize the loop of related products

Tags: php, loop, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

A question about WooCommerce/Wordpress

Is there a way to recognize which loop you are in?

If I wanted use the hook woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title only in the loop of related products, how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 10):

from https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-conditional-logic-ultimate-php-guide/

```
global $woocommerce_loop;
if ( is_product() && $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) {
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','your_custom_function',20);
}
```